# how to call ios functions from watch kit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watch

I am working on iOS project and they ask me to make Apple Watch application that related to our iOS application
I need to call iOS function if the user clicked on Apple Watch button 
then I want to send message from iOS app to the watch
I don't know how to do it , any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this documentation, there is also sample code provided: 
[Using Watch Connectivity to Communicate Between Your Apple Watch App and iPhone App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/using_watch_connectivity_to_communicate_between_your_apple_watch_app_and_iphone_app)

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to call telephony framework. Put below code in Watch function

```
let contactNumber = "1234567890"

if let callTelUrl = URL(string: "tel:\(contactNumber)"){
     let wkEXt = WKExtension.shared()
     wkEXt.openSystemURL(callTelUrl)                
}
```

Happy Coding...:)